# Measure for year wise trends of employees whose experience less than 6 months

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have an employee data which include  employees still in the organisation and  the details of employees left from the organisation. how can we create a measure for total employees whose experience < 6 moths in an year wise?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to replace the table and column names with the right ones - the functions you need are CALCULATE, DISTINCTCOUNT, and FILTER

```
EmpCtLessThanSixMo:=CALCULATE(
   DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[EmployeeCode]),
   FILTER(Table1,Table1[MonthsEmployed]<=6)
)
```